# Step size and wolfe conditions for the BFGS-method in R package optim

Tags: r, optimization

I am using the `optim`-function in `R` to optimize my likelihood with the BFGS algorithm and I am using the [book](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/num_optimization.pdf) 'Numerical Optimization' from Nocedal and Wright as reference (Algorithm 6.1). The algorithm states that the step size $\alpha_k$ should satisfy the Wolfe conditions. I was wondering if this happens in the `optim`-function or if it uses a fixed step size? I couldn't find it in the documentation, but I thought maybe the control argument `ndeps` equals the step size $\alpha$?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on R-help (https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help).  John Nash (see the references in `?optim`) is a frequent contributor to that list.